# How to get response of observable in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have consumed an http url having json response

```
 [
    {
    _id: "5a22ff88a06b10436a9da55f",
    updatedOn: "2017-12-02T19:31:20.026Z",
    createdOn: "2017-12-02T19:31:20.026Z",
    createdBy: "Vishal Patel",
    status: "o",
    penddate: "2017-12-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    pstartdate: "2017-12-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    name: "vishal patel",
    epmid: "e100",
    pid: "1000",
    __v: 0
    }
    ]
```

in .service.ts file using the following code

```
getProjects(): Observable<MaterialList[]> 
{
return this.http.get<MaterialList[]>(this.url)
.pipe(
tap(projectlist => this.log(`FetchedList`)),
catchError(this.handleError('getProjects',[]))
);

}
```

in `abc.component.ts` file

used this

```
projectlist: MaterialList[] = [];

this.getProjectsList.getProjects().subscribe(projectlist => this.prrojectlist = projectlist['']);
```

I have checked using this as well

```
this.getProjectsList.getProjects().subscribe(projectlist => { this.prrojectlist = projectlist['']});
```

but not able to get response in `this.projectlist`.

I have followed heroes tutorial from [angular.io](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#tap-into-the-observable)

Please help I am new to Angular2 typescript2.

Comment: what is the value of `this.projectlist` in console

Comment: value in console for this.projectlist is []

Comment: you have a type at `this.prrojectlist ` have you changed it

Comment: yes i have changed it

Comment: have you tried using `return this.http.get<MaterialList[]>(this.url).map( resp => var data = resp.json()) ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned blank array to your result array.

Please modify your code from this `this.getProjectsList.getProjects().subscribe(projectlist => this.prrojectlist = projectlist['']);` to this `this.getProjectsList.getProjects().subscribe((data) => this.prrojectlist = data);`

Comment: glad to help you